# Global grunt task error handling

Tags: gruntjs

Grunt will output exit codes and that's fantastic for scripts executing grunt tasks but I want the ability to handle failed grunt tasks after grunt completes them.

I was expecting to find some type of error handling function that I could set in the initConfig somewhere but I don't see anything. Likewise, even a "finally" function would work nicely.

Basically, I have an alias task that is a set of tasks that I execute and one of them temporarily changes content of a file and I write the content back to disk after everything completes. I want to still be able to at least attempt to write the content back to disk even if tasks after the mutation occurs, fail.

Something to this affect would be great.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    onError: function (error) {
        // execute my file cleanup
    },

    // this is essentially a "finally" function that executes once grunt 
    // finishes with all tasks.
    onComplete: function () {
        // execute my file cleanup
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure, that there is no such feature. But it is a popular request: [1](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/542), [2](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1184).

What can be done by now? You can write a custom grunt-task, something like the following:

```
var errorCb = function() { callback(); }
var doneCb = function() { callback(); }
grunt.initConfig({
    task_runner: {
        before: ...,
        beforeEach: ...,
        run: ['other_task1', 'other_task2'],
        after: ...,
        afterEach: ...,
        onError: errorCb,
        onComplete: doneCb
    },
    other_tasks: { ... }
});
```

And register your task:

```
grunt.registerTask('task_runner', "Tasks' lifecycle", function(task, message) {
    // foreach task in tasks: grunt.task.run(task)
    ...
    // except(`grunt.util.error`)
});
```

As I know, there is no beatiful way to get the result of a task run. So here comes the [monkey-patching](https://github.com/cowboy/javascript-hooker). It is possible to hook these functions: [`grunt.fail`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/fail.js) and `grunt.log.error`.

Here's some [inspiration](https://github.com/aleclarson/grunt-then): [1](https://github.com/dylang/grunt-notify), [2](https://github.com/antiBaconMachine/grunt-graceful). Also, have a look at [`grunt-then`](https://github.com/aleclarson/grunt-then).

All in all, I can not say that it is an easy task. I hope someday Grunt will have events (by now: "Note that Grunt doesn't yet emit any events, but can still be useful in your own tasks.").

P.S. Have you considered Gulp for your project?

P.S.S If you are going to write your custom task, feel free to ask me for a  contribution.